# WebDriver does not recognize element

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait

I'm trying to make `Selenium` wait for a specific element (near the bottom of the page) since I have to wait until the page is fully loaded.

I'm confused by it's behavior.

I'm not an expert in `Selenium` but I expect this work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    def load_page():
        driver.get('http://www.firmy.cz/?geo=0&q=hodinov%C3%BD+man%C5%BEel&thru=sug')
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, 'Zobrazujeme')))
        html = driver.page_source
        print html

    load_page()
```

TIMEOUT:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 78, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I'm just trying to see the `HTML` of the fully loaded page. It raises `TimeoutException` but I'm sure that that element is already there. I've already tried another approach.

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="companyTitle"]')))
```

But this approach raises error too:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
Message: Unable to locate element:
{"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@class=\"companyTitle\"]"}
```

Comment: your goal is just to get `html` of a page or this is a part of more complecated task? using `selenium` is mandatory ?

Comment: Try giving implicit time as well since its page load

Answer (score 0):

Loading the site takes a long time, use [implicitly waiting](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#implicit-waits).

In this case, when you are interested in the whole `HTML`, you don't have to wait for a specific element at the bottom of the page.
The `load_page` function will print the `HTML` as soon as the whole site is loaded if you give the browser enough time to do this with `implicitly_wait()`.

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# wait max 30 seconds till any element is located
# or the site is loaded
driver.implicitly_wait(30)


def load_page():
    driver.get('http://www.firmy.cz/?geo=0&q=hodinov%C3%BD+man%C5%BEel&thru=sug')
    html = driver.page_source
    print html

load_page()
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in your code is wrong selectors.

If you want to wait till web element with text `Zobrazujeme` will loaded and then print page source:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

def load_page():
    driver.get('http://www.firmy.cz/?geo=0&q=hodinov%C3%BD+man%C5%BEel&thru=sug')
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME , 'switchInfoExt')))
    html = driver.page_source
    print html

load_page()
```